# My database is stored on AWS RDS. Unfortunately my aws rds instance is deleted. Where it is stored in my computer

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My mysql database is stored on AWS RDS. Unfortunately my aws rds instance is deleted. Can anybody knows where it stores in local in (my computer).

Thanks

Comment: Unless you made a copy on your computer, it's not stored there at all.

Comment: If you really nuked your AWS database instance without backing it up locally, then you're probably out of luck.  Take this as a lesson to perhaps backup your data if this matters to you.